# Can I use a Google Cloud Storage object as the payload for an AutoML Vision request?

Tags: python, google-api, python-requests, google-cloud-storage, google-cloud-automl

I have a trained model from the Google AutoML Vision API. I want to use this model to predict labels on a set of images that I have stored in a Google Cloud Storage Bucket.  Google provides some sample code for calling the predict function:

```
def get_prediction(content, project_id, model_id):
    prediction_client = automl_v1beta1.PredictionServiceClient()
    name = 'projects/{}/locations/us-central1/models/{}'.format(project_id, model_id)
    payload = {'image': {'image_bytes': content}}
    params = {}
    request = prediction_client.predict(name, payload, params)
    return request  # waits till request is returned
```

I was wondering if there is a way to directly have the object from the Storage bucket be the payload? I haven't found any ways to do this yet. If this is not possible then I'm guessing I would have to download the image from the storage bucket and convert it to bytes for the payload? If this is the case is there a way to get the bytes from Cloud Storage without downloading the image?

Answer (score 0):

This is not currently supported, but is a known feature request. Stay tuned!

Comment: If anyone else if having this issue I found a workaround.  `payload = {'image': {'image_bytes': GCS_image.download_as_string()}`